# Can SPI used for shift register(serial to parallel) CD4094

Tags: serial-port, stm32

I have a project like below. I am trying to send the data using SPI but the LEDS are not glowing in sending pattern.

```
      I am new to STM32. Could anyone please let me know if SPI can be used in this scenario OR not.
```

STM32f207 ======> RS232 ======> CD4094 ==========> LEDS (1 to 8)

CD4094 (serial to parallel communication)

## Code Snippet::

uint8_t test = 0xFF;

status = HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, (uint8_t*)&test,1,100);

Thanks,

Rajasekhar.

Comment: This question is probably better suited for https://electronics.stackexchange.com as the answer depends on how you wire the chip, what the supply voltage is, whether the CD4094 can drive LEDs etc. And I'm a bit confused about "RS232". Did you mean "SPI" instead? Overall, I think – if done right – it should be possible.

Comment: Are you driving the *strobe* pin correctly?

Comment: The chip includes a strobe pin. Data from each stage of the shift register is latched on a negative transition of the strobe input. The output data latch is transparent when strobe is high. If you are using SPI, you could use the CS pin of your SPI to drive the strobe pin.